# Is there a way to enforce synchronous function calls within node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, control-flow, event-loop

For example, the following is a basic node http server (from their official site), and we are passing a callback to `createServer()`. Is there any guarantee that the calls to `foo()` and `bar()` will be executed in that particular order, and the normal control flow will be maintained?

I know that in order to enqueue messages into a queue which is polled by the event loop, we must pass a callback function with `foo()` and `bar()`. But is it guaranteed that the event loop won't mess with the control flow if I call the functions the way I just did.

Note: I actually **want** to enforce this control flow (let's think of `foo()` and `bar()` as functions that will eventually do error checking on the incoming HTTP request without doing anything particularly I/O intensive (I am assuming `console.log` isn't that I/O intensive, **correct me if I am wrong**)).

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    foo();
    bar();
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

function foo()
{
    console.log('This is foo');
}


function bar()
{
    console.log('This is bar');
}
```

Comment: Study this question and answer carefully to understand how javascript eventloop works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795369/nodejs-execution-context . Your should then realize that your example code does not enter the eventloop between foo and bar and therefore the code sequence is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `foo()` and `bar()` do not yield control of the event loop, and so they always get executed in your intended order, and before the `res...` commands.

Comment: Here is a rough way to think about it.  While your code is running, nothing else is running, and so your code is always synchronous. No I/O happens while your code runs, and you can only make requests to send I/O or tell the code what to do later when it receives I/O.